# conan to download generic zip from artifactory

Tags: c++, build, conan

I have a **test** repository of Generic type in Artifactory which holds some zip files.
I would like to download those packages using the conan.

I have added that remote succesully.

```
conan remote add conan-af https://artifactory.domain.dev/artifactory/api/conan/test
```

With `conan remote set-auth` I have done the login as well.

Now I have folder and file in that repo: **components/FA/fa.zip**

As I saw with `conan install --requires` I will not be able to download non-conan package? Am I wrong???

So I tried option **conan download**

```
conan download -r conan-af https://artifactory.domain.dev/artifactory/api/conan/test/components/FA/fa.zip
```

Error:
**ERROR: 404: Repo 'test' was not found. [Remote: conan-af]**

While if I paste the same URL in browser, or use curl, my file is being downloaded automatically

How I can download it or install it using conan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `conan remote add` or Conan remotes in general only work with Conan repositories, not generic ones. You need to configure a Conan repository in your server and then pass the URL to it in the `conan remote add myrepo <url>` (note this URL in case of Artifactory is provided by the SetMeUp, it is not the browser URL)

Comment: thank you very much for your comment and efforts to help. so it must be a conan repository that is set up? generic or maven repositories are not supported to be targeted in order to download some source code or binary packages?

Comment: is it not possible in some way to store in cache source code files (extracted) from zip that will be later on used in "conan install" with deploy or generate? I managed to do that with locally created packaged being stored in cache... now I would like to do something similar for source code packages retrieved from the artifactory?

Comment: drodri please comment if there is some way by using the conan to download the package from non-conan repository in Artifactory? And later on to install that package in our main project. Thanks!

Comment: The conversation is already going in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/15966 ticket.